# Python module is installed using repository folder name, not package name

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have a git repository - let's call it called `foo-bar` - but for whatever reason the package is called `foo_bar` (i.e. in `src/foo_bar` and defined in `pyproject.toml`).

```
[project]
name = "foo_bar"
```

In the past this hasn't been a problem, and the package installs with the `_` name (including the most recent test workflow in our CI). However recently installs have been failing because the package seems to install using the repository folder name (with the hyphen) instead. We use `pip install -e .` after setting up dependencies, and this has worked historically.

Is there a way to force pip to respect the module name in pyproject.toml? And has this behaviour changed recently (as of late '23)? I understand generally Python will use the folder name for the module, but in this case I think users should be able to set whatever they like as the clone folder without it affecting the install (and the source folder is named correctly); for example in the past I've had multiple versions of the same repository downloaded with slightly different names.

It's not a huge issue to change the repo name (I suspect this is bad form), or even the package name at this point, but I'm curious why this stopped working.

Comment: The name of the [distribution package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Distribution-Package) and the name of the top-level [import package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Import-Package) are not the same thing and can have different values. Nowadays distribution project names are normalized into "kebab case" `foo-bar`. There was some effort made very recently to enforce this normalization more seriously. But `pip install foo_bar`, `pip install foo.bar`, and `pip install foo_bar` should still all deliver the same result.